# Why Jasmine is called a "BDD" testing framework even if no "Given/When/Then" supported?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, cucumber, bdd

In the introduction of [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html), it says:

> Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code.

I read several articles of BDD, and seems we should use 'Given/When/Then' to define "Scenario"s, which is what "cucumber" does. But in Jasmine, I can't see any of such methods.

Can we still call Jasmine a "BDD" testing framework even if it doesn't have such concept?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd describe Jasmine as a unit testing framework for javascript that has alot of syntactic sugar so that we can write our 'tests' more as specifications that describe behaviour. Mostly we use Given, When, Then when we are describing/specifying the overall behaviour of a system in the language of the business. When you are describing a component of a system, using natural language generally has fewer benefits - the greater detail required at lower levels of abstraction is better supported by a programming language.

Now unit testing is a fundamental part of BDD, and jasmine supports this in a way that allows us to specify behaviour fairly eloquently, so yes it can definitely be a BDD testing tool/framework even if it only targets lower levels of abstraction.

Cucumber only targets higher levels of abstraction. The fact that its pants at writing low level specifications doesn't make it any less a BDD testing framework (BDD collaboration tool).

An interesting point is that to do BDD you really need two different testing tools, one to do the high level abstraction stuff, and another to do the lower level detailed specification stuff. Different tools for different tasks that are both part of the same process.

Finally GWT really is just an implementation detail of scenario writing. Its a way of differentiating

- setting up state G
- describing an action W
- examining the consequences of the action T

Comment: Thanks for you great answer, and sorry for my English, I can't understand this sentence well `The fact that its pants at writing low level specifications doesn't make it any less a BDD testing framework`, could you use an easier expression?

Comment: Sorry, sentence is saying just because cucumber is not good at driving one part of the BDD lifecycle (the TDD bit of doing lower level tests) it doesn't mean that it isn't a good BDD tool. The same standard should apply to Jasmine. It may not be good at doing what Cucumber is good at, but its very good at doing the low level stuff whilst supporting one of the key ideas of BDD which is to specify rather than test.

Comment: But isn't BDD starting to code from testing, so you write teh tests firt and then they fail and you write the code? I guess Jasmine can be used for testing after something is coded right?

Comment: @Tester You can test after code as well with any framework, BDD or TDD, just call to tool against the code. And while TDD focus on *when* to test, BDD is more about *how* to test.

Answer (score 21):

Jasmine does not prevent you from using given-when-then, below is an example showing two ways you could use given-when-then whilst using Jasmine.

```
describe("Given a string containing 'foo'", function(){
    var someString;
    beforeEach(function() {
        someString = "foo";
    });
    describe("When I append 'bar'", function(){
        beforeEach(function() {
            someString += "bar";
        });
        it("Then the string is 'foobar'", function(){
            expect(someString).toBe("foobar");
        });
    });
    it("When I append 'baz' Then the string is 'foobaz'", function(){
        someString += "baz";
        expect(someString).toBe("foobaz");
    });
});
```

Find a style that works for you. You should ensure that the test description describes effectively what you are testing. You can use the given-when-then style sentence as a tool to ensure that your test description is precise about what is being tested.

Comment: I use this style all the time and most of the BDD frameworks do a good job at grouping your describes and its as well as nicely indenting them.` PASS  ui/tests/reducers/drawerreducer.spec.js
  Toggling the navigation drawer
    Given the drawer is closed and the action type is TOGGLE_DRAWER
      ✓ it should toggle the drawer state isOpen to true (2ms)
      ✓ and the current state is not passed, it should toggle the drawer state isOpen to true (2ms)
    Given the drawer is closed and the action type is not TOGGLE_DRAWER
      ✓ it should return the current state as is`

Comment: Hi how can you use nested describe ? As per Jasmin , describe is for the testsuite and it for testcases .

Answer (score 1):

To respond to @PDHide's question: It is allowed in Jasmine.

> Hi how can you use nested describe ? As per Jasmin , describe is for the testsuite and it for testcases

[The docs](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite) say:

> #### Nesting describe Blocks
>
> Calls to `describe` can be nested, with specs defined at any level. This allows a suite to be composed as a tree of functions. Before a spec is executed, Jasmine walks down the tree executing each `beforeEach` function in order. After the spec is executed, Jasmine walks through the `afterEach` functions similarly.

The also say:

> The `describe` function is for grouping related specs [...]